# Subclass MKAnnotationView

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, mkmapview, mkannotationview

Did somebody ever override successfully the method `setDragState` in `MKAnnotationView`?
If I try to google for it with "`mkannotationview setDragState`" I only get three hits! One of them is my other post on stackoverflow ;)

The reference says that when subclassing `MKAnnotationView` the subclass has to care about  the dragstate. But it does not say how to exactly. Only setting the dragstate to `MKAnnotationViewDragStateDragging` or rather `MKAnnotationViewDragStateCanceling` seems not to be enough. Because if I just do that, one of the issues for example is that the mapview does not receive the `mapView:annotationView:didChangeDragState:fromOldState:` delegate function.

I tried to override it by setting the dragState also in the super class. But at this point other errors occur: For example if I drag the annotationView and my finger runs off the screen, the app crashes with something like "can not remove observer for keypath dragstate" (but my subclass does not any observers I know about). So it seems to that there are other things to care of.

In this post on apple developer forum https://devforums.apple.com/message/203107#203107 aroonicus, a guy from apple, mentions that you have to override [MKAnnotationView setDragState:] but sadly he does not tell how to.

Can anybody help? Does anybody know howto override setDragState? Did anybody created a working subclass of MKAnnotationView overriding setDragState?

Bye,

Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer this thread
refer to the second answer where a custom annotation view class is used to override the existing one. It works

[Subclassing MKAnnotationView and overriding setDragState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677166/subclassing-mkannotationview-and-overriding-setdragstate)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using custom annotations. See the following sample project: http://digdog.tumblr.com/post/1616858395/note-about-mapkitdraganddrop-3-2