# Custom MKAnnotation with drag & drop animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

I have an annotation with custom image and drag'n'drop support. But I need to animate the annotation the same way default Google pin is animated. That means the annotation should "jump up" when I drag it and "fall down" when I release it.

I was quite surprised that this animation isn't working anymore when I change annotation's image.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer here: [Subclassing MKAnnotationView and overriding setDragState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677166/subclassing-mkannotationview-and-overriding-setdragstate). I used bad keywords when I was trying to find the answer before.