# Selecting a location with MapKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

Is there a best practice or common pattern for allowing users to select a precise location on a map using MapKit?

I've seen examples where a user can enter an address in a search box.  But what about the case where a user doesn't know the exact address and wants to select a location from the map?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit more complex task than it seems.

[Here is the guide how to detect single taps on a Web View.](http://mithin.in/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way)

I've used the same pattern to detect single taps on Map View but allowing zooming and dragging at the same time.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that replicating the Maps application is close to a best practice for map applications.

You can test it for yourself; tap and hold somewhere on the map and a pin that you can move around by dragging will be dropped where you held your finger.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps app seems to tackle what is a reasonable idea by touching the map by instead allowing you to drop a pin on the map; the SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677166/subclassing-mkannotationview-and-overriding-setdragstate) might help out.