# iOS MapKit dragged annotations (MKAnnotationView) no longer pan with map

Tags: ios, properties, ios7, mapkit, key-value-observing

I'm learning to use MapKit in my fledgling iOS app. I'm using some of my model entities as annotations (added the `<MKAnnotation>` protocol to their header file). I also create custom MKAnnotationViews and set the `draggable` property to `YES`.

My model object has a `location` property, which is a `CLLocation*`. To conform to the `<MKAnnotation>` protocol, I added the following to that object:

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D) coordinate {
    return self.location.coordinate;
}

- (void) setCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)newCoordinate {
    CLLocation* newLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]
        initWithCoordinate: newCoordinate
        altitude: self.location.altitude
        horizontalAccuracy: self.location.horizontalAccuracy
        verticalAccuracy: self.location.verticalAccuracy
        timestamp: nil];
    self.location = newLocation;
}

- (NSString*) title {
    return self.name;
}

- (NSString*) subtitle {
    return self.serialID;
}
```

So, I have the 4 required methods. And they're pretty straightforward. When I read the apple docs on `MKAnnotationView` and the `@draggable` property, it says the following:

> Setting this property to YES makes an annotation draggable by the user. If YES, the associated annotation object must also implement the setCoordinate: method. The default value of this property is NO.

And elsewhere, the `MKAnnotation` docs say:

> Your implementation of this property must be key-value observing (KVO) compliant. For more information on how to implement support for KVO, see Key-Value Observing Programming Guide.

I have read that (brief) document, and it is not clear at all to me what I'm supposed to do to accomplish that so that the `coordinate`, which I'm deriving from my `location` property is a proper  property in and of itself.

But I'm reasonably sure it's not working correctly. When I drag the pin, it moves, but then it no longer relocates when I pan the map.

**UPDATE**

So I tried playing with the stock MKPinAnnotationView. To do this, I simply commented out my delegate's `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` method. I discovered that these aren't draggable by default. I added the `mapView:didAddAnnotationViews:` to my delegate to set the `draggable` property of the added views to `YES`.

Once configured thus, the Pin views, as hinted by John Estropia below, seem to work fine. I decided to use the `mapView:annotationView:didChangeDragState:fromOldState:` delegate hook to get a closer look at what is going on:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState {
    NSArray* states = @[@"None", @"Starting", @"Dragging", @"Cancelling", @"Ending"];
    NSLog(@"dragStateChangeFrom: %@ to: %@", states[oldState], states[newState]);
}
```

For the stock pins, one will see log output that looks like this:

```
2014-02-05 09:07:45.924 myValve[1781:60b] dragStateChangeFrom: None to: Starting
2014-02-05 09:07:46.249 myValve[1781:60b] dragStateChangeFrom: Starting to: Dragging
2014-02-05 09:07:47.601 myValve[1781:60b] dragStateChangeFrom: Dragging to: Ending
2014-02-05 09:07:48.006 myValve[1781:60b] dragStateChangeFrom: Ending to: None
```

Which looks pretty logical. But if you switch to the configured `MKAnnotationView`, the output you will see looks like:

```
2014-02-05 09:09:41.389 myValve[1791:60b] dragStateChangeFrom: None to: Starting
2014-02-05 09:09:45.451 myValve[1791:60b] dragStateChangeFrom: Starting to: Ending
```

It misses TWO transitions, from Starting to Dragging, and from Ending to None.

So I begin to be skeptical that I need to do something different with properties. But I'm still frustrated with why this won't work.

**UPDATE 2**

I created my own `Annotation` object to stand between my model objects, which could have a property `coordinate` property. The behavior remains the same. It seems to be something with the `MKAnnotationView`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933632/dragging-the-map-after-dragging-my-mkannotationview-does-not-move-the-mkannotati which points to this possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4457772/467105

Comment: @Anna this helped a lot, thanks. I'm not subclassing, but the idea's the same mostly. I almost got it working. I'll post my solution, and ask a new question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are lots of examples about how to use the delegate method `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` that show setting up an `MKAnnotationView`. But what is not as obvious is that just because you set the `draggable` property of your `MKAnnotationView` instance to `YES`, you still have to write some code to help it transition some of the states. MapKit will take care of moving your instance's `dragState` to `MKAnnotationViewDragStateStarting` and `MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding`, but it will not do the other transitions. You see hints of this in the docs notes about subclassing `MKAnnotationView` and the need to override the `setDragState:animated:'

> When the drag state changes to MKAnnotationViewDragStateStarting, set the state to MKAnnotationViewDragStateDragging. If you perform an animation to indicate the beginning of a drag, and the animated parameter is YES, perform that animation before changing the state.
>
> When the state changes to either MKAnnotationViewDragStateCanceling or MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding, set the state to MKAnnotationViewDragStateNone. If you perform an animation at the end of a drag, and the animated parameter is YES, you should perform that animation before changing the state.

In this case, I'm not subclassing, but it seems that `MKAnnotationView` still struggles to make the transitions on its own. So you have to implement the delegate's `mapView:annotationView:didChangeDragState:fromOldState:` method. E.g.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
        annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView
        didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState
        fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState {
    if (newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateStarting) {
        annotationView.dragState = MKAnnotationViewDragStateDragging;
    }
    else if (newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding || newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateCanceling) {
        annotationView.dragState = MKAnnotationViewDragStateNone;}
    }
}
```

This allows things to complete appropriately, so that when you pan the map after dragging the annotation, the annotation moves with the pan.

Comment: Can someone explain why this answer hasn't been upvoted 100 times? This is _so_ important! Thank you (100 times).

Comment: you saved my life!  This solution is perfect

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a custom map pin? I saw this before as well. Seems to be a bug in iOS 7. As a workaround, we just ended up using the default pin for `MKPinAnnotationView`.

Comment: The MKPinAnnotationView's setCoordinate has the correct key value observing built in, that's why it works. See my answer for how to add it to your own setCoordinate method.

Answer (score 0):

Your setCoordinate was missing the required Key-Value observing methods (willChangeValueForKey/didChangeValueForKey) that are required for the map to detect when the annotation has been moved so it can move the annotation view to match, e.g.

```
- (void) setCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)newCoordinate {

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"coordinate"];

    CLLocation* newLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]
        initWithCoordinate: newCoordinate
        altitude: self.location.altitude
        horizontalAccuracy: self.location.horizontalAccuracy
        verticalAccuracy: self.location.verticalAccuracy
        timestamp: nil];

    self.location = newLocation;

    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"coordinate"];
}
```

Source:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/MKAnnotation/coordinate

*"Your implementation of this property must be key-value observing (KVO) compliant. For more information on how to implement support for KVO, see Key-Value Observing Programming Guide."*

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Apple wasn't clear in the docs, what they meant to say was the setCoordinate requires the Key-Value observing methods willChangeValueForKey & didChangeValueForKey that allow the map to detect when the annotation has been moved so it can move the annotation view to match, e.g.

```
- (void) setCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)newCoordinate {

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"coordinate"];

    CLLocation* newLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]
        initWithCoordinate: newCoordinate
        altitude: self.location.altitude
        horizontalAccuracy: self.location.horizontalAccuracy
        verticalAccuracy: self.location.verticalAccuracy
        timestamp: nil];

    self.location = newLocation;

    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"coordinate"];
}
```