# Dragged Annotation views do not move with maps

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotationview

I have a problem with my map after an annotation view is dragged:
when I change  the region panning the map, the dragged annotation remains fixed in the screen ( other annotation that have not been dragged are displayed correctly, the problem is on every annotation view that is dragged ; note that the annotation view continues to bel selectable for callout and dragging, the only problem that i can see is that it does not move when I pan Map )

I there any solution ? is this a known bug with ios 7.1 ? Or am i missing something in my code ?

Comment: Can you post the code for how you're adding annotations?

Comment: a video to explain: http://youtu.be/B49NanaTXL0

Comment: the annotation are simply added to map with addAnnotation: MyMapAnnotation *imagePM = ( MyMapAnnotation *) annotation;
            
            MyMapAnnotation *pin = (MyMapAnnotation*)[_delegate getAnnotation:self];
            pin = [pin init];
            
            pin.image = imagePM.image;

            [pin setCoordinate:imagePM.coordinate];
            [pin setTitle:imagePM.title];
            [pin setSubtitle:imagePM.subtitle];
            pin.identifier = imagePM.identifier;
            
            [_mapView addAnnotation:pin];

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567082/ios-mapkit-dragged-annotations-mkannotationview-no-longer-pan-with-map

Comment: thx, seems solved, doing manually do the transition to MKAnnotationViewDragStateNone ; i post the cose in the answer for future ref

Answer (score 2):

seems the code should care to do last transition to reset annotation view , this fixes the problem :

```
-(void)setDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)dragState animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setDragState:dragState animated:animated];
    if (dragState==MKAnnotationViewDragStateStarting) {
        [...
    } else if (dragState==MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding || dragState==MKAnnotationViewDragStateCanceling) {
        ...
        self.dragState = MKAnnotationViewDragStateNone;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If annotation is dragged then you have to set its drag state to none in its delegate method. This code solved my problem

```
    - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
     annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView
    didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState
       fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState
{
if (newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding)
    {
     ..... your code.....
    annotationView.dragState=MKAnnotationViewDragStateNone;
    }

}
```