# ios 7 MKMapView after drag an annotation, tap to dismiss the annotation title box, tap again seeing crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I am trying to implement a draggable annotation on MKMapView, referring to this post: [ios 7 MKMapView draggable annotation change it's position when map is scrolled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973236/ios-7-mkmapview-draggable-annotation-change-its-position-when-map-is-scrolled)

I am able to add the drag function to the annotation and it works fine, except I found this weird bug:

1. after you drag the annotation
2. tap on the map view, you will see the annotation title box will disappear
3. tap on annotation again, try to bring the annotation title box, it crashes every time.

I have put the source code at below links, anybody seeing the same problem before?
https://www.dropbox.com/s/t8ipu12zyh04wzf/MapViewTest-master%202.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the root cause, it is due to the annotation file I set. After change the annotation to something like:

```
@interface Annotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
```

it works properly now