# MKAnnotationView drag state ending animation

Tags: ios, mapkit, uiviewanimation, mkannotationview

I'm using the custom MKAnnotationView animations provided by Daniel here: [Subclassing MKAnnotationView and overriding setDragState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677166/subclassing-mkannotationview-and-overriding-setdragstate/4457772#4457772) but I run into an issue.

After the pin drop animation, when I go to move the map the mkannotationview jumps back to its previous location before the final pin drop animation block is called.

It seems to me that dragState=MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding is being called before the animation runs? How can I get around this issue and set the final point of the mkannotationview to be the point it's at when the animation ends?

```
#import "MapPin.h"

NSString *const DPAnnotationViewDidFinishDrag = @"DPAnnotationViewDidFinishDrag";
NSString *const DPAnnotationViewKey = @"DPAnnotationView";

// Estimate a finger size
// This is the amount of pixels I consider
// that the finger will block when the user
// is dragging the pin.
// We will use this to lift the pin even higher during dragging

#define kFingerSize 20.0

@interface MapPin()
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint fingerPoint;
@end

@implementation MapPin
@synthesize dragState, fingerPoint, mapView;

- (void)setDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newDragState animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(mapView){
        id<MKMapViewDelegate> mapDelegate = (id<MKMapViewDelegate>)mapView.delegate;
        [mapDelegate mapView:mapView annotationView:self didChangeDragState:newDragState fromOldState:dragState];
    }

    // Calculate how much to life the pin, so that it's over the finger, no under.
    CGFloat liftValue = -(fingerPoint.y - self.frame.size.height - kFingerSize);

    if (newDragState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateStarting)
    {
        CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(self.center.x,self.center.y-liftValue);
        [MapPin animateWithDuration:0.2
                         animations:^{
                             self.center = endPoint;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             dragState = MKAnnotationViewDragStateDragging;
                         }];

    }
    else if (newDragState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding)
    {
        // lift the pin again, and drop it to current placement with faster animation.

        __block CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(self.center.x,self.center.y-liftValue);
        [MapPin animateWithDuration:0.2
                         animations:^{
                             self.center = endPoint;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             endPoint = CGPointMake(self.center.x,self.center.y+liftValue);
                             [MapPin animateWithDuration:0.1
                                              animations:^{
                                                  self.center = endPoint;
                                              }
                                              completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                                  dragState = MKAnnotationViewDragStateNone;
                                                  if(!mapView)
                                                      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:DPAnnotationViewDidFinishDrag object:nil userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self.annotation forKey:DPAnnotationViewKey]];
                                              }];
                         }];
    }
    else if (newDragState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateCanceling)
    {
        // drop the pin and set the state to none

        CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(self.center.x,self.center.y+liftValue);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                         animations:^{
                             self.center = endPoint;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             dragState = MKAnnotationViewDragStateNone;
                         }];
    }
}

- (UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    // When the user touches the view, we need his point so we can calculate by how
    // much we should life the annotation, this is so that we don't hide any part of
    // the pin when the finger is down.

    fingerPoint = point;
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem, especially under iOS 8. After many hours of testing I believe that iOS keeps track of where it thinks `self.center` of the annotation is during the time that the state is `MKAnnotationViewDragStateDragging`. You need to use extreme caution if you animate `self.center` when handling `MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding`. Read that as "I couldn't get that to work, ever."

Instead, I kept *Daniel*'s original code when handling states `MKAnnotationViewDragStateStarting` and `MKAnnotationViewDragStateCanceling`, I animated `self.center`.  When handling `MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding` I animated `self.transform` instead of `self.center`.  This maintains the actual location of the annotation and just changes how it is rendered.

This works well for me running either iOS 7.1 and iOS 8.0.  Also fixed a bug in `hitTest`, and added some code to reselect the annotation after dragging or canceling.  I think that is the default behavior of `MKPinAnnotationView`.

```
- (void)setDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newDragState animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(mapView){
        id<MKMapViewDelegate> mapDelegate = (id<MKMapViewDelegate>)mapView.delegate;
        [mapDelegate mapView:mapView annotationView:self didChangeDragState:newDragState fromOldState:dragState];
    }

    // Calculate how much to lift the pin, so that it's over the finger, not under.
    CGFloat liftValue = -(fingerPoint.y - self.frame.size.height - kFingerSize);

    if (newDragState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateStarting)
    {
        CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(self.center.x,self.center.y-liftValue);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                         animations:^{
                             self.center = endPoint;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             dragState = MKAnnotationViewDragStateDragging;
                         }];

    }
    else if (newDragState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding)
    {
        CGAffineTransform theTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -liftValue);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                         animations:^{
                             self.transform = theTransform;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             CGAffineTransform theTransform2 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
                             [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                                              animations:^{
                                                  self.transform = theTransform2;
                                              }
                                              completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                                  dragState = MKAnnotationViewDragStateNone;
                                                  if(!mapView)
                                                      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:DPAnnotationViewDidFinishDrag object:nil userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self.annotation forKey:DPAnnotationViewKey]];
                                                  // Added this to select the annotation after dragging.
                                                  // This is the behavior for MKPinAnnotationView
                                                  if (mapView)
                                                      [mapView selectAnnotation:self.annotation animated:YES];
                                              }];
                         }];
    }
    else if (newDragState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateCanceling)
    {
        // drop the pin and set the state to none
        CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(self.center.x,self.center.y+liftValue);

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                         animations:^{
                             self.center = endPoint;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             dragState = MKAnnotationViewDragStateNone;
                             // Added this to select the annotation after canceling.
                             // This is the behavior for MKPinAnnotationView
                             if (mapView)
                                 [mapView selectAnnotation:self.annotation animated:YES];
                         }];
    }
}

- (UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    // When the user touches the view, we need his point so we can calculate by how 
    // much we should life the annotation, this is so that we don't hide any part of
    // the pin when the finger is down.

    // Fixed a bug here.  If a touch happened while the annotation view was being dragged
    // then it screwed up the animation when the annotation was dropped.
    if (dragState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateNone)
    {
        fingerPoint = point;
    }
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: I put this aside for a while but have just gone back to it to try to implement your code and it worked great. Hero.